# how to change screen brightness , when automatic brightness is on?

Tags: android

```
public static void setBrightness(Activity activity, Float brightness) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (0 < brightness && brightness <= 1) {
        lp.screenBrightness = brightness;

    }
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}
```

I use this code to change screen brightness ,but it doesn't work when automatic brightness is on.

how can I change screen brightness , when automatic brightness is on ? And I wan't change the system brightness ,it should be only change current activty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to turn off the automatic brightness:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
```

If you want to set it back to automatic again use this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
```